# XPath to parse xml within WS xml response

Tags: xml, xpath

I query a WS that I can Parse with XPath //*[local-name()='someparentnode']
The result of that xpath retrieves an xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Response xmlns="SOMETHING">    
    <SOMEDATA>OK</SOMEDATA> 
    <SOMEDATA1>110075700011</SOMEDATA1> 
    <ResponseOK>        
        <SOMEDATA3>123123</SOMEDATA3>       
        <SOMEDATA4>asda</SOMEDATA4> 
    </ResponseOK>   
</Response >
```

I need the value of SOMEDATA3 but when i try doing //*[local-name()='someparentnode']/Response/ResponseOK/SOMEDATA3 i get nothing

I have no idea what is happening. Any help or information is really appreciated since I need this for my work

Thanks in advance for the people that takes sometime for helping others!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that descendant elements without prefix inherit default namespace from ancestor, implicitly. This means, in the given XML, all elements are in namespace 'SOMETHING', so you need to use `local-name()` for each element in your XPath :

```
//*[local-name()='someparentnode']
 /*[local-name()='Response']
 /*[local-name()='ResponseOK']
 /*[local-name()='SOMEDATA3']
```

Comment: So this will be //*[local-name()='someparentnode']/*[local-name()='Response']/*[local-name()='ResponseOK']/*[local-name()='SOMEDATA3'] ??

Comment: I must say that that xpath didnt retrieve any result :/

Comment: Maybe without ` *[local-name()='someparentnode']` part .. since there is no such element in the XML you posted

Comment: I have a soap WS that when i do //*[local-name()='someparentnode'] i get the posted xml, its like an xml inside another and can't parse anything below the "someparentnode" node